# DRF override default router path

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

When i register viewset in SimpleRouter i get paths like

```
    [get] objects/
    [post] objects/
    [get] objects/{id}
```

etc.

Is there a way to replace default post route with its detailed version?
like `[post] objects/{id}`

I've tried to replace it with action in viewset

```
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'], url_path="my-path"):
        def my_action:
            ...
```

but all i've got is

`[post] /objects/{id}/my-path`

and default post path is still there

Best what i managed is to remove post method from viewset and then add separate APIView explicitly to urls

```
path("objects/<uuid:project_pk>/", CreateAPIView.as_view()),
```

But i concerned there is a better way with some router/viewset settings